# PHP + MySQL: Padding out array to count months without views in site stats

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a web app for measuring website statistics using view, site login and user creation records that are stored in the website's database.
*(The statistics you'll see now aren't real, they're from a QA environment.)*

I want to build a [multi-axis graph using Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/multi-axis.html) where the vertical axis would represent the amount of views and the horizontal axis would be the twelve months of the year; but the more specific the filters get (*i.e., amount of views in one page from any and all people who live in a certain country, state/province **and** city*), the app will bring sets of records with months missing (months for which there are no view records in the database), like so:

```
object(stdClass)#12 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" ["month"]=> string(1) "6" ["view_count"]=> string(4) "3210" }
object(stdClass)#14 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" ["month"]=> string(1) "7" ["view_count"]=> string(4) "1605" }
object(stdClass)#15 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" ["month"]=> string(1) "8" ["view_count"]=> string(3) "292" }
object(stdClass)#16 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2021" ["month"]=> string(2) "11" ["view_count"]=> string(1) "8" }
object(stdClass)#17 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "1" ["view_count"]=> string(1) "1" }
object(stdClass)#18 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "2" ["view_count"]=> string(1) "2" }
object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "3" ["view_count"]=> string(2) "14" }
object(stdClass)#20 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "4" ["view_count"]=> string(2) "27" }
object(stdClass)#21 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "5" ["view_count"]=> string(2) "42" }
object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "6" ["view_count"]=> string(3) "166" }
object(stdClass)#23 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "7" ["view_count"]=> string(2) "21" }
object(stdClass)#24 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "8" ["view_count"]=> string(1) "7" }
object(stdClass)#25 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(1) "9" ["view_count"]=> string(1) "6" }
object(stdClass)#26 (3) { ["year"]=> string(4) "2022" ["month"]=> string(2) "10" ["view_count"]=> string(2) "33" }
```

For padding out missing months at the beginning, I tried this:

```
$first_month = intval($this->page_monthly_views[0]->month);

if($first_month > 1) {

  for($i = 1; $i < $first_month; $i++) {
    $padding_month = (object) [
      'year' => $this->page_monthly_views[0]->year,
      'month' => strval($first_month - $i),
      'view_count' => '0'
    ];
    array_unshift($this->page_monthly_views, $padding_month);
  }

}
```

but then as you can see in the records listed above, there are months missing that aren't necessarily before the first recorded month in a time period, so for example if I padded up to month number 6 for all records corresponding to the year 2020, but then months number 8 and 10 were missing, this solution wouldn't cover that issue.

For going through every year of which there exist records, I started with this:

```
$years = [];

foreach($this->page_monthly_views as $ind => $month) {
  if(!in_array($month->year, $years))
    $years[] = $month->year;
}
```

But then I noticed that if I used foreach for everything, and then nested foreach loops, then I'd have to go through the entire list of records a probably excessive amount of times.

So, I'm looking for the most practical way to do the following steps without having to do 3 or more foreach's to achieve what I want:

1. Getting the different years (in this case 2020, 2021, 2022) for which there are records
2. For each year, going through groups of records corresponding to each year and padding out any months for which there aren't records with "blank" records (where the value of "view_count" would be 0 (or "0" as a string))

Do I need to do some advanced PHP work for this, or can this be avoided altogether by using a specific SQL function to pad out months without views and display '0'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your exact desired json output from your sample mysql resultset?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is use a relatively small query to find out which years you'll need to instantiate ahead of time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `year` FROM your_stats ORDER BY `year` ASC;
```

Then instantiate your array something like this:

```
foreach ( $result as $row ) {
  $years[$row['year']] = [1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0, 11=>0, 12=>0];
  }
```

At that point you have a filled array, so just fill in the months for which there is data available.